# How to sort listings in search page in wpgeodirectory?

Tags: wordpress

The sort by option dissapears in search page whereas it appears in show all listings.

How to show also the sort by in "search page" ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

plugins\geodirectory\geodirectory-functions\custom_functions.php 
line 622

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    return;
}
```

and comment return

```
if ( is_search() ) {
//  return;
}
```